# Initialize a 2d array with unknown first dimension size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, multidimensional-array

Say I need a 2d array, first dimension size set at runtime, and second dimension size is set to 5 at compilation time.

Since we can do this to initialize a 1d array with unknown size

```
int* arr;
arr = new int[12];
```

I would like to make the following code work

```
int* arr[5];
arr = new int[12][5];
```

Notice:

I need the second dimension set to 5, not first dimension. So I need to be able to do `arr[11][4]` but not `arr[4][11]`.

I know I can make `arr` an `int**` and then assign a 2d array to arr, so please avoid such answer.

I know I can use STL containers such as vector, so please avoid such answer.

Comment: `I know I can make arr an int** and then assign a 2d array to arr, so please avoid such answer.` -- Why? -- `I know I can use STL containers such as vector, so please avoid such answer.` -- Why?

Comment: I know a screw can be driven in with a screwdriver, so please avoid such answer

Comment: There are quite a few "_I know_"s in the question.- What is the question exactly?

Comment: *Since we can do this to initialize a 1d array with unknown size* -- I think this is where the misunderstanding of what can be done with a 2d array starts.

Comment: Why what? @PaulMcKenzie Is this hard to see that I want to achieve something through an idea that I am not familiar with. This is how you get new pieces of knowledge.

Comment: Given a definition `int *arr[5]` (which is an array of five `int *`) no assignment to `arr` is valid, since an array cannot be assigned.    As such, there is no answer to the question.    Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: @Peter I think they acknowledge that that code is incorrect and are asking for some correct code to accomplish the task

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - as written - it is seeking a solution to an unsolvable problem,  and the OP "knows" so much that answers providing alternatives can't be given.

Comment: @Peter ???? Then you need to suggest a better declaration. What do you mean there is not an answer

Comment: @Jraxon -- Did you read M.M. comment about the screwdriver?  That's why I (and any sane C++ programmers) would ask "why?"

Comment: It is not a matter of "laziness".  When a programmer writes code, they are usually not in a bubble.  Others have to read and use the code.  If it is obfuscated, that helps no one.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First, this piece of code is only 2 lines long. Second, I don't think this kind of technology is top notch and very few people know it. Third, look at M.M's answer, do those lines look confusing to any C++ programmer??

Comment: It is not the idiom that most C++ programmers use to declare a 2 dimensional dynamic array.  Obfuscation can come with just two lines of code -- the number of lines does not matter.

Comment: A obfuscation for you doesn't mean it might be one for others. This website is for people to come ask and answer questions. I don't understand your intention here. Also, I simply want to know a simple functionality in C++, so why should I care about what most C++ programmers do?? Your comments are really irrelevant. Try to avoid those comments

Comment: The comment section is for comments.  I commented on a strange demand that you posted in your question.  That is what the comment section is for, and that is to ask questions such as "why?" and see where the rationale of making such demands (as in your post) comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
int (*arr)[5];

arr = new int[12][5];
```

Then you can access elements such as `arr[11][4]`.  But not `arr[12][5]` as you suggest in the question, arrays are zero-indexed and the maximum element index is one less than the dimension.

All dimensions except the innermost must be known at compile-time. If the `5` is actually meant to represent a runtime value then you cannot use C-style arrays for this task .

NB. Consider using `unique_ptr` for safe memory management. The code would be `auto arr = std::make_unique<int[][5]>(12);`.

Comment: order won't matter?  is that or this: int (*arr)[12];   true?

Comment: @nonock my code has 12 rows and 5 columns. your suggestion would be for something with 12 columns